# How to use performSelectorOnMainThread method in my program

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am new to objective c and so developing the basic programs.In my project I have a View Controller which has two text fields and a segment control for which two more view controller a linked namely first view controller and second view controller, My problem is whenever I enter data in the textfields of main view controller(namely:Segment View controller) its not getting passed into other view controllers. In this scenario how should i use performSelectoronMainTread method.Below is my code.Please help me.

```
  Thanks in advance


  #import "SecondViewController.h"
  #import "FirstViewController.h"
  #import "SegmentControlViewController.h"

  @interface SegmentControlViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

  @end

  @implementation SegmentControlViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


  self.textField1.delegate = self;
  self.textField2.delegate = self;
  self.firstView.hidden = false;
  self.secondView.hidden = true;

 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }



  - (IBAction)segmentControlPressed:(id)sender {


     switch (self.segmentControlButton.selectedSegmentIndex) {
      case 0:
        self.firstView.hidden = false;
        self.secondView.hidden = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.firstView.hidden = true;
        self.secondView.hidden = false;
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
 }

  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
   FirstViewController *firstViewController1 = [[FirstViewController 
   alloc]init];
   SecondViewController *secondViewController1 = [[SecondViewController 
   alloc]init];
   [firstViewController1 displayTextValu:self.textField1.text ];
   [secondViewController1 displayTextValu:self.textField2.text];
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return true;

  }


 }


 @end
```

firstViewcontroller.m

```
    #import "SegmentControlViewController.h"
    #import "FirstViewController.h"

    @interface FirstViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
    @end

    @implementation FirstViewController

    -   (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }
  }

  -(void)displayTextValu:(NSString *) label{
   self.firstNameLabel.text = label;
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
   }

   @end
```

Similarly second view controller is written.How to update textfield data into firstViewController's firstNameLabel

Comment: from where you are displaying  firstviewcontroller and secondviewcontroller?

Comment: firstViewControllrs and secondViewControllers are in connect with the firstView and secondView respectively. So im my  segmentControlPressed method I am calling these View controllers

Comment: You mean you are adding object of Firstviewcontrlller.view and secondviewcontorller.view in firstview and secondview?  firstvireController.view is Subview in Firstview?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new objects of first and second view controllers, use instance variables. Initiate them in viewDidLoad. Also, add NSString variables in you first and second viewcontrollers, like

`NSString *firstLabelText;`

and in your textƒieldDidEndEditting, try setting the variable value. 
Just check this method

Answer (score 0):

Modify calls to view controllers like that:

```
[firstViewController1 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayTextValu:) withObject:self.textField1.text waitUntilDone:NO];
```

but you don't need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread`, try this GCD call:

```
NSString *text1 = self.textField1.text;
NSString *text2 = self.textField2.text;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [firstViewController1 displayTextValu:text1 ];
    [secondViewController1 displayTextValu:text2];
});
```